# How do I properly select a certain part of an image inside a picture box in C# and highlight it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been trying to write a program, to be able to load an image on a form and select a rectangle on it, then load that rectangle onto another picture box (pictureBox2), and I also want to be able to highlight what I have selected on the original picture, in pictureBox1, as I move my mouse.

So far I have this code, but it doesn't properly respond to the mouseMove event, the rectangle that I highlight isn't selected properly. What is the problem?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap original;
    bool isSelecting;
    int x0, y0, x1, y1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picOriginal_MouseDown);
        pictureBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(picOriginal_MouseMove);
        pictureBox1.MouseUp   += new MouseEventHandler(picOriginal_MouseUp);
    }

    #region helpder methods

    // Start selecting the rectangle.
    private void picOriginal_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(original != null)
        {
            isSelecting = true;
            // Save the start point.
            x0 = e.X;
            y0 = e.Y;
        }
    }

    // Continue selecting.
    private void picOriginal_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(original != null)
        {
            // Do nothing it we're not selecting an area.
            if(!isSelecting) return;

            // Save the new point.
            x1 = e.X;
            y1 = e.Y;

            // Make a Bitmap to display the selection rectangle.
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(original);

            // Draw the rectangle.
            using(Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
            {
                gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red,
                    Math.Min(x0, x1), Math.Min(y0, y1),
                    Math.Abs(x0 - x1), Math.Abs(y0 - y1)
                    );
            }

            // Display the temporary bitmap.
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(bm, new Size(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
        }
    }

    // Finish selecting the area.
    private void picOriginal_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(original != null)
        {
            // Do nothing it we're not selecting an area.
            if(!isSelecting) return;
            isSelecting = false;

            // Display the original image.
            pictureBox1.Image = original;

            // Copy the selected part of the image.
            int wid = Math.Abs(x0 - x1);
            int hgt = Math.Abs(y0 - y1);
            if((wid < 1) || (hgt < 1)) return;

            Bitmap area = new Bitmap(wid, hgt);
            using(Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(area))
            {
                Rectangle source_rectangle =
                    new Rectangle(Math.Min(x0, x1), Math.Min(y0, y1),
                        wid, hgt);
                Rectangle dest_rectangle =
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, wid, hgt);
                gr.DrawImage(original, dest_rectangle,
                    source_rectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            // Display the result.
            pictureBox2.Image = area;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(original != null)
        {

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files(*.*)|*.*";
        if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            original = new Bitmap(dialog.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(original, new Size(pictureBox1.Width,     pictureBox1.Height));
        }
        dialog.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: At the location `Save the new point` I've added a warning. You are storing e.Y in x1. I would expect something like `y1 = e.Y;` there.

Comment: Right, I'm gonna correct that, thanks, however it still doesn't select it properly, the rectangle doesn't get selected precisely..

Comment: I guess the problem is in the picOriginal_MouseUp method, when I write using(Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(area)){} I don't get anything output to the pictureBox2

Comment: Can't repro the problem with your posted code.  PictureBox2 shows the selected image from PictureBox1.  Try telling us more about the PictureBox properties and the image being used.

Comment: The problem is resolved, thanks

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018629/calculate-coordinates-for-rotated-text-plus-bounding-border -- its in VB, but it may help

Comment: Your code is highly insufficient and produces memory leak (creating a new bitmap for **every** mouse move event!). I suggest to use two bitmaps instead of creating constantly a new one. ps. I didn't downvote

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you mean by "insufficient", and I do need to draw the image anew for every mousemove event, because otherwise it doesn't draw the highlighting properly, if you have a better way of doing it, then tell me how you would go about it. And I don't understand how creating a new bitmap causes memory leaks.. Also, note that this is only my 3rd day using C#, I'm not very good at it.

Comment: In the picturebox paint event draw the rectangle. In *picOriginal_MouseMove* event after `x1 = e.X; y1 = e.Y;` just call *pictureBox1.Invalidate();*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the 'original' image size which is not the same as the picturebox size. Try this code to compensate for the zoom ratio between your 'original' image and the picturebox size:

```
            // Draw the rectangle.
            float zoomX = (float)original.Size.Width / pictureBox1.Width;
            float zoomY = (float)original.Size.Height / pictureBox1.Height;

            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
            {
                gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red,
                    Math.Min(x0, x1) * zoomX, Math.Min(y0, y1) * zoomY,
                    Math.Abs(x0 - x1) * zoomX, Math.Abs(y0 - y1) * zoomY
                    );
            }
```

This fixes the red rectangle in my case. But the copied part in picturebox2 is still not correct...

And this fixes the copy to the second picturebox:

```
            // Copy the selected part of the image.
            float zoomX = (float)original.Size.Width / pictureBox1.Width;
            float zoomY = (float)original.Size.Height / pictureBox1.Height;
            int wid = (int)(zoomX * Math.Abs(x0 - x1));
            int hgt = (int)(zoomY * Math.Abs(y0 - y1));
            if ((wid < 1) || (hgt < 1)) return;

            Bitmap area = new Bitmap(wid, hgt);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(area))
            {
                Rectangle source_rectangle =
                    new Rectangle((int)(zoomX * Math.Min(x0, x1)), (int)(zoomY * Math.Min(y0, y1)),
                        wid, hgt);
                Rectangle dest_rectangle =
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, wid, hgt);
                gr.DrawImage(original, dest_rectangle,
                    source_rectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
```

Comment: Yes, this is okay, I actually don't really care about that because I know that I resized the picture to the size of the picture box, however, once I omitted the resizing it was all good, but I still don't get anything in pictureBox2 and that's what's bothering me.

Comment: hmm, i works as intended over here... Just copied your code in a new form, added 2 pictureboxes and compensated for the zoom ratio.

Comment: You even mentioned it yourself: "the copied part in picturebox2 is still not correct..."

Comment: Oh, never mind, i screwed up the Action thing, in the form editor