# Drawing Diagonal Text all over Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm using the following code to draw inclined text all over an image. This works, but not as intended.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
String text = "TextTile";

Font font = new Font(DefaultFont.Name, 20);
SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
int textwidth = size.ToSize().Width;
int textheight = size.ToSize().Height;

int y_offset = (int)(textwidth * Math.Sin(45 * Math.PI / 180.0));

//the sin of the angle may return zero or negative value, 
//it won't work with this formula
if (y_offset >= 0)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x += textwidth)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y += y_offset)
        {
            //move to this position
            g.TranslateTransform(x, y);

            //draw text rotated around its center
            g.TranslateTransform(textwidth, textheight);
            g.RotateTransform(-45);
            g.TranslateTransform(-textwidth, -textheight);
            g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0);

            //reset
            g.ResetTransform();
        }
    }
}

pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

This is the result of the code

[image: image1]

What I'm, looking for is something like the image below. You can see there are multiple lines of text in the same line. How would I set the font size of the text so that the image is watermarked properly.

[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Jen's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23019404/2330053) to find the bounding box of the rotated text.

I start in the top left of the bitmap and start drawing a diagonal line of repeating text going up and to the right. Each time the line goes off the right or top edge, I start a new diagonal line by adding twice the total height of the line. As I draw each diagonal line of text, I track whether one of the starting coords is within the bounds of the bitmap. When I find an entire line that didn't cross the bitmap then I know we're done.

*Oh, I see your Leo DiCaprio and up you with a Chris Hemsworth.

> When i try to change the direction of the text from top left to bottom
> right using 45 instead of -45 angle, i see a gap in the left portion
> of the image.

Modified code to handle both directions.

Note the two different calls to `Watermark()` with parameters:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Watermark(pictureBox1, WatermarkDirection.BottomLeftToTopRight, "Do not copy!");
    Watermark(pictureBox2, WatermarkDirection.TopLeftToBottomRight, "Proof");
}

enum WatermarkDirection
{
    BottomLeftToTopRight,
    TopLeftToBottomRight
    
}

private void Watermark(PictureBox pb, WatermarkDirection direction, String text)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pb.Image);
    Rectangle rcBmp = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), bmp.Size);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    Font font = new Font(DefaultFont.Name, 20);
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
    int textwidth = (int)size.Width;
    int textheight = (int)size.Height;

    int angle = (direction == WatermarkDirection.BottomLeftToTopRight) ? -45 : 45;
    int y_main = Math.Abs((int)(textwidth * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0)));
    int x_main = Math.Abs((int)(textwidth * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0)));
    int y_add = Math.Abs((int)(textheight * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0)));
    int x_add = Math.Abs((int)(textheight * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0)));
    int totalX = x_main + x_add;
    int totalY = y_main + y_add;

    // keep going down until we find a line that doesn't cross our bmp
    Rectangle rcText;
    bool intersected = true;
    int multiplier = (direction == WatermarkDirection.BottomLeftToTopRight) ? 1 : -1;
    int offset = (direction == WatermarkDirection.BottomLeftToTopRight) ? -totalY : 0;            
    for (int startY = totalY; intersected; startY += (2 * totalY))
    {
        intersected = false;
        int x = (direction == WatermarkDirection.BottomLeftToTopRight) ? 0 : (bmp.Width - totalX);
        int y = startY;
           
        rcText = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y + offset), new Size(totalX, totalY));
        if (rcBmp.IntersectsWith(rcText)) { intersected = true; }
        while (((direction == WatermarkDirection.BottomLeftToTopRight) && (x <= bmp.Width || y >= 0)) ||
                ((direction == WatermarkDirection.TopLeftToBottomRight) && (x >=0 || y >= 0)))
        {                    
            g.TranslateTransform(x, y);
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0);
            g.ResetTransform();
            
            x += (totalX * multiplier);
            y -= totalY;
            rcText = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y + offset), new Size(totalX, totalY));
            if (rcBmp.IntersectsWith(rcText)) { intersected = true; }
        }
    }
    pb.Image = bmp;
    g.Dispose();
    font.Dispose();
}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.This works great :) I had another question.When i try to change the direction of the text to - `from top left to bottom right` using`45` instead of `-45` angle , i see a gap in the left portion of the image.Please see https://imgur.com/a/svxodFz

Comment: I'll post an update from my work computer.

Comment: See modified post and code.